# How to handle moved/renamed pages links in Docusaurus v2?

Tags: docusaurus

@Actito we have our Developers Portal hosted as a Docusaurus v2 website.

We start to work more and more on content, and for consistency/better structure aspects we regularly rework the pages structures/hierarchy

What is the right way to handle those moves without our users facing broken pages (bookmarked) ?

Can we setup something to do with routing so as to store redirections from former links to new ones ?

I would be happy to hear about that

Thanks a lot for your help !

KR,
Marc

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [plugin-client-redirect plugin](https://docusaurus.io/docs/api/plugins/@docusaurus/plugin-client-redirects) to create redirects. The syntax is straightforward:

```
type RedirectRule = {
  to: string;
  from: string | string[];
};
```

I'm using this and it works OK. The problem is that list of redirects can get quite big over time. You also must take special care of the page that have custom slugs.

If you can do server-side redirects, it would be better to use them.

Comment: Ok thx a lot I'll have a look at it tomorrow !

Comment: And it works as expected !

Comment: I'm glad that I was able to help you. I must say that working with redirects is one of my least favorite things when it comes to Docusaurus.

Comment: On my side it's more like an acceptable workaround to avoid having to deal with NGINX redirections on which I've not the hand. Anyway it's not something I'd like to use extensively

Comment: Sure, I get it. My advice would just be, to keep an eye on chain redirects that might occur after some time.